# How to delete a file after checking whether it exists

Tags: c#, .net, windows

How can I delete a file in C# e.g. `C:\test.txt`, although apply the same kind of method like in batch files e.g.

```
if exist "C:\test.txt"

delete "C:\test.txt"

else 

return nothing (ignore)
```

Answer (score 468):

This is pretty straightforward using the [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) class.

```
if(File.Exists(@"C:\test.txt"))
{
    File.Delete(@"C:\test.txt");
}
```

---

As [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576139) pointed out in the comments, you don't actually need to do the `File.Exists` check since `File.Delete` doesn't throw an exception if the file doesn't exist, although if you're using absolute paths you will need the check to make sure the entire file path is valid.

Comment: That test isn't actually needed. See my post.

Comment: The test is necessary if you want to prevent a possible DirectoryNotFoundException.

Comment: The test shouldn't be used in place of exception handling tho, but rather in conduction with it. Any number of scenarios can result in the exists check returning true and Delete throwing.

Comment: Why's there an `@` before the file path? For me it works without.

Comment: @ keeps you from having to double up the backslashes.

Comment: Note:  `File.Delete(path);` DOES throw an exception if it can't delete the file for some reason, though -- I have gotten `Unknown error "1346".` before.

Answer (score 132):

Use [System.IO.File.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx) like so:

`System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\test.txt")`

From the documentation:

> If the file to be deleted does not exist, no exception is thrown.

Comment: That will throw a DirectoryNotFoundException if "The specified path is invalid (for example, it is on an unmapped drive)."

Comment: How odd. Intellisense says `An exception is thrown if the specified file does not exist`.

Comment: Perhaps you're using a different version of the .NET framework?

Comment: I'm using .Net4, it looks like the intellisense is wrong I have run a check and no exception is thrown

Comment: Yeah I tried and just `System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\test.txt");` is enough. Thanks

Comment: Note:  `File.Delete(path);` DOES throw an exception if it can't delete the file for some reason, though -- I have gotten `Unknown error "1346".` before.

Comment: Check if directory exists before trying to delete file, otherwise 'DirectoryNotFoundException' will be thrown. 'if (!Directory.Exists(@"C:\"))'

Answer (score 49):

You could import the `System.IO` namespace using:

```
using System.IO;
```

If the filepath represents the full path to the file, you can check its existence and delete it as follows:

```
if(File.Exists(filepath))
{
     try
    {
         File.Delete(filepath);
    } 
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      //Do something
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why not just issue the Delete call regardless and catch any exception that indicates that the file didn't exist?

Comment: There are more exceptions that can be thrown, I suppose.

Answer (score 34):

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\test.txt"))
    System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\test.txt"));
```

but

```
System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\test.txt");
```

will do the same as long as the folder exists.

Answer (score 27):

If you want to avoid a `DirectoryNotFoundException` you will need to ensure that the directory of the file does indeed exist. `File.Exists` accomplishes this. Another way would be to utilize the `Path` and `Directory` utility classes like so:

```
string file = @"C:\subfolder\test.txt";
if (Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(file)))
{
    File.Delete(file);
}
```

Answer (score 17):

```
  if (System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Public\DeleteTest\test.txt"))
    {
        // Use a try block to catch IOExceptions, to 
        // handle the case of the file already being 
        // opened by another process. 
        try
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\Users\Public\DeleteTest\test.txt");
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 15):

```
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    File.Delete(path);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are reading from that file using FileStream and then wanting to delete it, make sure you close the FileStream before you call the File.Delete(path). I had this issue.

```
var filestream = new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\Test\PutInv.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite);
filestream.Close();
File.Delete(@"C:\Test\PutInv.txt");
```

Comment: Or use a `using` statement, where the `File.Delete()` would go outside the brackets.  In the example you have, you should also do a `filestream.Dispose();`.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(rootFolder, authorsFile)))    
{    
// If file found, delete it    
File.Delete(Path.Combine(rootFolder, authorsFile));    
Console.WriteLine("File deleted.");    
}
```

**Dynamic**

```
 string FilePath = Server.MapPath(@"~/folder/news/" + IdSelect)
 if (System.IO.File.Exists(FilePath + "/" + name+ ".jpg"))
   {
    System.IO.File.Delete(FilePath + "/" + name+ ".jpg");
   }
```

**Delete all files in a directory**

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(rootFolder);    
foreach (string file in files)    
{    
File.Delete(file);    
Console.WriteLine($"{file} is deleted.");    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you want to delete a file whatever the case(whatever the exception occurs ,please do delete the file). For such situations.

```
public static void DeleteFile(string path)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                return;
            }

            bool isDeleted = false;
            while (!isDeleted)
            {
                try
                {
                    File.Delete(path);
                    isDeleted = true;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                }
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
        }
```

Note:An exception is not thrown if the specified file does not exist.

Comment: So you are trying to delete file 20 times per second until it's deleted. What if, for some reason, file can't be deleted and program will try to delete it forever? I don't think this is good solution.

Comment: At the very least, you should provide a timeout parameter.

Comment: @kv1dr right. I think you should try for a limited time and return a failure message if the file wasn't deleted.

Answer (score 0):

This will be the simplest way,

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath)) 
{
  System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
}
```

`Thread.sleep` will help to work perfectly, otherwise, it will affect the next step if we doing copy or write the file.

Another way I did is,

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
{
System.GC.Collect();
System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
}
```