# How to delete zip folder programmatically?

Tags: c#, zip

I want to delete a zip folder if it is exists. I have below code.

```
string zippath = @"C:\Neenu\Downloads.zip";
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(@"" + TemporaryFolder, @"" + zippath);
```

Just before the above code I want to check if folder exists or not. If exists I want to delete folder.

Comment: [Directory.Exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Take a look at the functions in System.IO.Directory

Comment: No File.Exists. Mind that a zip folder is just an ordinary file.

Comment: Which folder do you want to check? `TemporaryFolder`? Folder in zip-archive (though you create new, not adding)? It's not clear what you want to achieve, can you give us a better example/explanation of the problem?

Comment: I want to delete Downloads.zip

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a file after checking whether it exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391711/how-to-delete-a-file-after-checking-whether-it-exists)

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant `How to delete zip file` and not a folder.

Here, this should be easy:

```
File.Delete(zippath);
```

For deleting inner files and directories :

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);

foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
{
    file.Delete(); 
}
foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
{
    dir.Delete(true); 
}
```

Comment: `File.Exists` is not necessary, in fact it can cause a race condition error.

Comment: Thank you. Yes i want to Delete all the files inside zip folder and finally ZIP file also

Comment: So? The file could (theoretically) be created by another process. Just because the example in the question allows checking if the file exists, it's still unnecessary. So why add additional unneccesary code? Why teach someone a bad practice?

Comment: @Stijn Theoretically the above comment could have been typed by a Bot.

Comment: @NeenuSurendranK - i realized that `File.Exists` is not required, there is no exception if the file does not exists at all.

Answer (score 1):

Refer below code
I am keeping a copy of txt file and after that creating a new one
If you wish to delete file without vreating backup than jst use File.Delete(path of file)

```
if (File.Exists(file_path))
            {
                new_file_path = file_path.Replace(".txt", " created on " + File.GetLastWriteTime(file_path).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh-mm-ss tt") + ".txt");
                File.Move(file_path, new_file_path);
                File.Delete(file_path);
            }
```