# Effective Way to Delete File using Native Methods in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, native-methods

I am looking for a way to **delete files** using **Native Methods** in the most efficient and proven way in **C#**

Comment: what's wrong with [File.Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.delete?view=net-6.0)? could you please elaborate what _problem_ you're trying to solve?  i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete a file after checking whether it exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391711/how-to-delete-a-file-after-checking-whether-it-exists) Don't mind that the post also includes "after checking...", this question is so fundamental that there isn't going to be an existing post for just that.

Comment: .NET already uses the most efficient and proven way, it uses a [native function](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,303).  Necessarily so, deleting a file is an OS operation and the OS is native.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool DeleteFile(string lpFileName);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool DeleteFileA([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string lpFileName);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool DeleteFileW([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string lpFileName);
```

Use **DeleteFileW** for Unicode names and **DeleteFileA** for ANSI names.
**Sample Code:**

```
String filePath = @"C:\Data\MyFile.txt";

bool deleted = DeleteFileW(filePath);
if (!deleted)
{
     int lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
     Console.WriteLine("Failed to delete '{1}': error={0}", lastError, filePath);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you're calling windows APIs rather than the .Net methods such as File.Delete?

Comment: The question concerns native methods, not popular .NET methods such as File.Delete()

Comment: That depends on your definition of "native". I'd consider anything "native" to be stuff that comes with .Net framework.